# Change geometry of last page

Tags: geometry, layout

I am using KOMA Script class and need to change the layout of the last page.  Let's say. the last page should have an increased top section.

I've tried different ways, but none was successful.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% This does not work
\AtEndDocument{\newgeometry{top=85mm}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

%% This should be executed automatically!
\newgeometry{top=85mm}
\lipsum[9-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need another layout for the last page? I'm asking because, e.g., if the last page should have another top margin, does it also have a special content? In this case, I would bind the change of the margin to that content. Maybe even a change would be needed, but only something like a `\vspace*{…}` to shift that special content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it would be useful to know the reason for the changed page layout of the last page. For example, if there will be a special content at that page, the change of the top margin could be bound to that content. Or if the content of the last page should just be bottom aligned, this also could have another solution. But because your question was more general, about changing the setting of `top` with `geometry` package for the last page, here is a suggestion for exactly this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{%
  \ifnum \c@totalpages=\numexpr\@abspage@last-1\relax
    \newgeometry{top=85mm}%
    \global\textheight=\textheight
    \global\topmargin=\topmargin
    \global\@colht=\textheight % maybe not needed
    \global\@colroom=\textheight % maybe not needed
    \global\vsize=\textheight % maybe not needed
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-8]

%% This should be executed automatically!
%\newgeometry{top=85mm}
\lipsum[9-12]

\end{document}
```

After at least two LaTeX runs it results in:

[image]

For also changing the left or right margin or the height of the page header additional global changes of lengths could be needed, but this wasn't the question.

Just one additional note: Loading `geometry` already changes the margins of `scrartcl`. If you don't want this, you can use either KOMA-Script option `usegeometry` or `geometry` option `pass`.

Comment: Reason for the change is, that I am producing a journal.  The addresses of the recipients will be printed into the top area of the last page, therefore changing the top margin via geometry seemed to be the easiest way, to keep this area free of text.

Comment: @Jan Journals usually have their own production process and you don't need to care for such things. If they accept LaTeX code, they usually either provide a class/template that should be used unchanged, or they accept standard `article` class documents without special geometry settings. Unfortunately there are also journals that do not accept LaTeX documents but only MS Word.

Comment: Unfortunately, they only accept a ready to print PDF file.  Even more unfortunately: articles to be incorporated to this journal may be submitted via WORD and I have to convert them to LaTeX.  It seemed to be the easiest solution to me.  Any suggestions on how to spare out an address area on the last page will be highly appreciated.